# ld.exe: cannot find -lscrap_sys when I try to compile go-scrap

Tags: go

I've been trying to compile the [go-scrap](https://github.com/cretz/go-scrap) program on windows, but I've always got the following error

> C:/Program
>   Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lscrap_sys collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

From what I understand, the `lscrap` library on windows is needed.

Does anyone know what are the correct steps to compile the go-scrap program on windows correctly?